# Avoid locking service if process crashes / hangs

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am currently developing a windows service which implements [fileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky). Videos are uploaded into a folder at which point the filewatcher fires the created event as below to convert the video.

```
private void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  if (ConvertVideo(e.FullPath, e.Name))
  {
    WriteToEventLog(String.Format("Successfully converted video - {0}", e.FullPath), EventLogEntryType.Information);
  }            
}
```

Within `ConvertVideo` a new process is created but I have run into issues where the process crashes / hangs / disappears and it appears the main thread is then locked as its waiting for `WaitForExit()` which effectively crashes the service as no other videos can then be converted. How could I avoid locking the entire service if the process dies?

```
private bool ConvertVideo(string SourcePath, string Filename)
{   
   try
   {
      // Create new process
      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
      startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      startInfo.FileName = "C:\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe";
      startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      startInfo.Arguments = GetArguments(SourcePath, Filename);
      int? exitCode = null;
      using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
      {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        exitCode = exeProcess.ExitCode;
      }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```

*NOTE: Code is shortened for this example*

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN, [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) should return if your process crashes (emphasis added):

> When an associated process exits (that is, when it is **shut down** by the
>   operation system through a **normal or abnormal termination**), the system
>   stores administrative information about the process and returns to the
>   component that had called WaitForExit().

It appears that your HandBrake process is just hanging and staying alive.  The best solution would be to debug that process and figure out where it is crashing, but not closing down.  Do you have access to the HandBrakeCLI.exe code?

**If you don't have access to the HandBrake.exe code:** you could use [Process.WaitForExit(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx) to set a timeout. If the timeout is reached, you may want to manually kill your process via the [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3s566a) function, or all subsequent calls to [Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb) will not work properly, since they will only return a new process if the process wasn'talready running:

> A new Process component that is associated with the process resource,
>   or **null if no process resource is started (for example, if an existing
>   process is reused)**.

Comment: This is interesting, cant debug Handbrake code but may be able to view it as its a open source app. http://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php Ive looked at the timeout for waitforExit() as mentioned to Ken but wasnt sure. It may be the solution though.

Answer (score 1):

1)
You should spawn your process and wait for it to terminate in a separate thread, in order to avoid blocking your main thread.

2)
You could use the [`WaitForExit` method that takes the max time to wait for the process as a parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx). You'll then be able to avoid the case a thread of your program is blocked forever.

Comment: Hi Ken, I had looked at the second suggestion but as some of the videos can be quite large (up to 100MB) the timeout needs to be quite large which whilst the thread isnt blocked forever it is locked for a long time. Any suggestions as to the best method of threading the process off?

Comment: If you spawn another thread for the call, you will still need to make sure that you wait for the process to finish before calling Process.Start again. Process.Start will return null if your process is already running.